# In Laravel, can I opt out of the additions $appends applies to a Model for particular database calls?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've inherited a Laravel API codebase, with no personal prior Laravel exposure.

One issue I'm facing is the Controller returning more than I'm explictly asking for.

For example, a User has all the usual things - first_name, last_name, email etc...

Users also have Courses they are subscribed to, and Lessons they've completed etc.

In the User model, `$appends = [...]` is used with some `setThisAttribute` functions to load the model with data from those associated models. I can see why the previous developers did this, because it's extremely convenient for some of the API calls being made.

I understand all this so far.

What I want to do sometimes though is just get the User data I explicitly ask for.

In a Controller I might write something like (very simple example):

```
$users = User::select('users.id', 'users.first_name')->get();
```

I want to receive:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    first_name: "Jackson"
  },
  ...
]
```

But instead I'm currently getting something like:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    first_name: "Jackson",
    courses: [...lots of data...],
    lessons:  [...even more data...]
  },
  ...
]
```

The difference in the actual responses in question is < 100ms to download what I want to the client, versus > 10s with the $appends stuff overloading the model.

Is there a way to opt-out of the $appends additions for *some* DB calls, or do I have to rewrite the whole API to explicitly ask for what is needed in the places where $appends is currently relied upon?

Comment: There isn't a way to easily exclude `$appends` attributes, because they're added automatically when the model is JSON encoded. I would say that the current method of implementation is a poor decision, and that relations should have only been eager loaded as and when required.

Comment: @fubar thanks. I feared that was the case. "I would say that the current method of implementation is a poor decision" is something I've been saying for the last couple of months, as it happens :)

Comment: One option might be to change the custom accessors to only include the courses and lessons, where the relationship has been eager loaded. So if you don't explicitly load those relations it instead just returns an empty array. To make this backward compatible, you'd have to figure out where this data *is* needed, and eager load the relationships accordingly in those instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

On your return you can use:

```php
$users = User::select('users.id', 'users.first_name')->get()->makeHidden(['courses', 'lessons']);
```

Comment: You beautiful human being! I'll bequeath my first born to you! You've just saved what I was projecting to be several days of work :)